# Simplification of a logic equation

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I am trying to simplify this logic function: $$g(x,y,z)=xy+x'z+yz$$ without Carnot (just Boole algebra). I tried going like this $$(x\cup y)\cap(x'\cup y)\cap(z\cup y)$$ and then using the distributive property of sets but it leads nowhere. Thanks in advance

Comment: In the last union, use commutativity.

Answer (score 1):

$$g(x,y,z)=xy+x'z+yz $$
Last term $yz$ has a common variable with the first two terms. This suggests to combine it with the first two as:
$$\begin{align}g(x,y,z)&=xy+x'z+\color{blue}{yz}\\ &= xy+x'z+\color{blue}{yz(x+x')}\\ 
&=xy+\color{blue}{xyz} + x'z + \color{blue}{x'yz}\\
&=xy(1+z)+x'z(1+y)\\
&=xy+x'z
\end{align}$$

Because $x+x'=1$ and $1+z=1$

Comment: Sorry but I made a mistake

Comment: Can you check the function for xy+ x'z+zy

Comment: Ah ok. That's fine, I will. Just a sec.. :)

Comment: updated @BillIconomou see if it makes sense